# Set Appearance for tablebiew in EKEventEditViewController using ios5 appearance protocol

Tags: iphone, ios5, eventkit, appearance

OK, I am trying without succes to change the appearance of the tableview presented by the EKEventEditViewController. I think I should be able to do this, but basically nothing is happening.

Case 1 set the background view for the tableview

```
    UIImageView *bkgrnd = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; 
bkgrnd.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Portrait2_Left1.png"];
    [[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EKEventEditViewController class], nil]
    setBackgroundView:bkgrnd];
```

Case 2 set the background color for all UITableViewCells.  Should be straight forward, but does not wlrk for the EKEventEditViewController.

`[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

And if you are wondering if EKEventEditViewController conforms to the appearance protocol, the documentation says it does.

Any ideas?